# "How one function parameters connects with another function parameters in javascript?"

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I was creating this facebook user login system basic logic in javascript. The logic is not my own but I am learning logics from these kind of codes. it is the logic of my online javascript teacher I got almost 90% idea of this code.

```
var database = [{
    username: "Robin",
    password: "abc"
  },

  {
    username: "Alex",
    password: "123"
  },

  {
    username: "John",
    password: "2222"
  }

];

var newsFeed = [{
    username: "Ron",
    timeline: "Well, I like facebook"
  },

  {
    username: "Alex",
    timeline: "Hello my friends"
  }

];

usernamePrompt = prompt("What is your username?");
passwordPromt = prompt("Enter your password now");

function isUserValid(username, password) {

  for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
    if (database[i].username === username &&
      database[i].password === password) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

// prompt input is firstly taken in this SignIn fuction.
//but it seems like isUserValid firstly takes input from popmt.
//I am so confused with the connection between these functions.
function SignIn(user, pass) {

  if (isUserValid(user, pass)) {
    console.log(newsFeed);
  } else {
    alert("Wrong password, Please try again later");
  }

}

SignIn(usernamePrompt, passwordPromt);
```

The code is working 100% correct. Problem is the logic is not so much clear in mind  to understand.

Comment: Just a note, never store plain passwords in javascipt (clientside).

Comment: @Mark In fact, never store plain text passwords *anywhere* :-)

Comment: @Bergi Amen to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var database = [
    {
        username: "Robin",
        password: "abc"
    },

    {
        username: "Alex",
        password: "123"
    },

    {
        username: "John",
        password: "2222"
    }

];
database is an array JSON object, which stores usernames and pssswords.

var newsFeed = [
    {
        username: "Ron",
        timeline: "Well, I like facebook"
    },

    {
        username: "Alex",
        timeline: "Hello my friends"
    }

];
```

Newsfeed is a array o objects which stores the usernames and their timeline update.

```
usernamePrompt = prompt("What is your username?");
passwordPromt = prompt("Enter your password now");
```

prompt is an alert with an input field, the data entered in that field is assigned to the respective variables.

```
function isUserValid(username,password){
        for(var i=0; i < database.length; i++){

        if(database[i].username === username &&
            database[i].password === password) {
            return true;
        }

    }   return false;
}
```

isUserValid is a function which takes arguments username and password, runs a loop for the length of the database array and checks for every object if the entered username and password exists in the database or not. If it does, it returns true else returns false.

```
function SignIn(user, pass) {

    if(isUserValid(user,pass)) {

        console.log(newsFeed);

    } else {
        alert("Wrong password, Please try again later");
    }

}

SignIn(usernamePrompt,passwordPromt);
```

The function signin also takes arguments username and password and the isuservalid function is called inside an if block to check if the user exists, iff it does it prints that users newsfeed else gives error message. In the end the signin function is called with the promps data takem before.

Answer (score 0):

The function isUserValid(username,password) takes a username and password and returns true or false if the user is valid. Nice function, does 1 thing.

The function SignIn(user, pass) is getting the user logged. This function calls isUserValid with the same arguments to check if the user is ok or not.

You could merge it all together but sometimes it is good to keep things in nice clean functions.

I think you may be a little confused about the order of how things happen, it's not the order you see in your script.

1. SignIn is called
2. isUserValid called from within SignIn
3. News feed or error message

Answer (score -1):

Okay. It starts here

```
usernamePrompt = prompt("What is your username?");
passwordPromt = prompt("Enter your password now");
```

These lines will prompt the user for username and password then store the data into the variables. After that, the main process starts here.

```
SignIn(usernamePrompt,passwordPromt);
```

This will call the function and also pass the given username and password along. Those two variables will be the input parameters for the following function, which will be used soon.

```
function SignIn(user, pass) {

    if(isUserValid(user,pass)) {

        console.log(newsFeed);

    } else {
        alert("Wrong password, Please try again later");
    }

}
```

In this function, it will first call

```
if(isUserValid(user,pass)) {
```

So it goes into this function

```
function isUserValid(username,password){
        for(var i=0; i < database.length; i++){

        if(database[i].username === username &&
            database[i].password === password) {
            return true;
        }

    }   return false;
}
```

and check if the username and password from the user is valid or not and return accordingly. It checks the validity by comparing the given username and password with every username and password in the database array. It will return true once it is found though otherwise it will return false because it is invalid.

Then back to this

```
if(isUserValid(user,pass)) {

    console.log(newsFeed);

} else {
        alert("Wrong password, Please try again later");
}
```

If the username and password from the user is valid then it will call

```
console.log(newsFeed);
```

which is just to console.log this array

```
var newsFeed = [
    {
        username: "Ron",
        timeline: "Well, I like facebook"
    },

    {
        username: "Alex",
        timeline: "Hello my friends"
    }

];
```

But if the username and password is invalid then it will execute this instead

```
alert("Wrong password, Please try again later");
```

Comment: `SignIn(usernamePrompt,passwordPromt);` does not call `usernamePrompt = prompt("What is your username?"); passwordPromt = prompt("Enter your password now");`, those two `prompt` statements are executed, before `SignIn(usernamePrompt,passwordPromt);` is executed.

Comment: @t.niese I edited my answer. Thank you for correcting it.